# How to check status of response from Polly?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I am downloading a `.tgz` file (max 100 MB) in a particular folder from a url with the below code and it works fine. I am using `HttpClient` along with `Polly` for timeout and retries.

```
private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient()
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};

private async Task<bool> Download(string fileUrl)
{
    var configs = await Policy
       .Handle<TaskCanceledException>()
       .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 3, sleepDurationProvider: i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
       .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
       {
           using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
           {
               httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
               return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
           }
       }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    File.WriteAllBytes("Testing/data.tgz", configs);
    return true;
}
```

As you can see in the above method, I am always returning true but it is not correct. I wanted to do below things:

- If for some reason I am not able to connect to the URL after x retries, then I want to return false and log it saying cannot talk to the url.
- Also if I am not able to create a file or write the byte array in a file on the disk then I want to return false as well. I am not sure when will this case happen but I want to protect us from this. Is this possible to achieve in my example?

For question one - I was reading more about Polly but couldn't find on how to check the response of Polly call after x number of retries and then act accordingly. And for question two - I am not sure on how we can do that. Also since I recently started working with C# (like few weeks maybe), I could be doing something wrong in my above code so if there is any better way, let me know.

Comment: Wrap it in `try-catch` and return `false` in the `catch` statement.

Comment: I thought I need to check for Polly response anyhow to do this. Is it not the case? @aepot

Comment: I'm not familiar with Polly but guessing that it must `throw` if something went wrong, thus you can `catch` it. Debug it (break it with wrong arguments) and you'll see if there some Exception was thrown, the reason to `return false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question there is a section on the page denoted to capturing the response

**Post-execution: capturing the result, or any final exception**

```
var policyResult = await Policy
              .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
              .RetryAsync()
              .ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => DoSomethingAsync());
/*              
policyResult.Outcome - whether the call succeeded or failed         
policyResult.FinalException - the final exception captured, will be null if the call succeeded
policyResult.ExceptionType - was the final exception an exception the policy was defined to handle (like HttpRequestException above) or an unhandled one (say Exception). Will be null if the call succeeded.
policyResult.Result - if executing a func, the result if the call succeeded or the type's default value
*/
```

**Update**

```
var policyResult = await Policy
   .Handle<TaskCanceledException>()
   .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 3, sleepDurationProvider: i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
   .ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () =>
   {
      using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync("Something").ConfigureAwait(false))
      {
         httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
   }).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Failure)
   return false;

try
{

    File.WriteAllBytes("Testing/data.tgz", policyResult.Result);      
    return true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{  
    // usually you wouldn't want to catch ALL exceptions (in general), however this is updated from the comments in the chat
    // file operations can fail for lots of reasons, maybe best catch and log the results. However ill leave these details up to you
    // log the results
    return false
}
```

Comment: yeah but I don't see `Outcome` and other properties on my `configs` variable and thats why I was confuse. I just need to figure out whether my URL call was successful or not in getting the data from it. It could be possible all retry failed so I want to protect from that.

Comment: @dragons `policyResult.Outcome` and you could also check your `policyResult.Result` for null. What other information do you need for instance?

Comment: yeah I understood that part but in my case do I need to change my `Policy` line? Bcoz as of now I cannot get those properties on my `configs` variable. It looks like I may have to change something then.

Comment: @dragons you need to use `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` not `ExecuteAsync`

Comment: got it. After trying that I am getting a compilation error after replacing `ExecuteAsync` with `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` method. Do you think you can provide an example on how to use that method with my example? it will help me understand better.